# What is the work of ClassLoader loadClass()

Tags: java

I have writen the small java class which I want to load by using ClassLoader.

```
public class ClassLoadingObj {

    public ClassLoadingObj(){
        System.out.println("---instantiating ClassLoadingObj ");
    }

    static{
        System.out.println("---Loading ClassLoadingObj");
    }
}
```

But when I executed the following code:

```
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("com.st.classLoader.ClassLoadingObj");
```

I find that the static block does not get executed.  My question is that if a class is loaded by using the `loadClass()` method, why are static blocks not executed in comparison to instantiating a class where static blocks always get executed.

Answer (score 3):

Actually static block gets executed when the class is **initialized** and it's a little bit different from **loaded**.

Before **initialized** class is **linked** and before that it is **loaded**, so there are 3 (or 4, including not-loaded) states of class.

[Here](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/lifetypeP.html) is well described how it works and what are the requirements for a class to become initialized.

An excerpt:

> The Java virtual machine specification gives implementations
>   flexibility in the timing of class and interface loading and linking,
>   but strictly defines the timing of initialization. All implementations
>   must initialize each class or interface on its first active use. The
>   following six situations qualify as active uses:
>
> - A new instance of a class is created (in bytecodes, the execution of    a new instruction. Alternatively, via implicit creation,
>     reflection,    cloning, or deserialization.)
> - The invocation of a static method    declared by a class (in bytecodes, the execution of an invokestatic    instruction)
> - The use or assignment of a static field declared by a    class or interface, except for static fields that are final and    initialized
>     by a compile-time constant expression (in bytecodes, the    execution
>     of a getstatic or putstatic instruction)
> - The invocation of    certain reflective methods in the Java API, such as methods in class    Class or in classes in the
>     java.lang.reflect package
> - The initialization of a subclass of a class (Initialization of a class    requires prior initialization of its superclass.)
> - The designation of    a class as the initial class (with the main()< method) when a Java    virtual machine starts up

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of class loader in java. Maybe the ClassLoader you use is the 
java.lang.ClassLoader, but the system won't use the this ClassLoader. You can try 
com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.util.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(), it will execute
the static block. More information you can reference to this 
page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader#Class_Loaders_in_JEE)